# Async call for computed property - Vue.js

Tags: ajax, vue.js

I have a computed property that will only be used if a match for a property exists. Because of this, I'm making the call to get the data `asynchronous` so that it's only retrieved when needed. I'm having an issue though trying to make an `async` call to return data for a computed property.

Below is what I have:

```
new Vue({
    el: "#formCompleteContainer",
    data: {
        form: {},
        components: []
    },
    computed: {
        employeeList: function () {
            var self = this;
            if (_.some(this.components, function (component) {
                return component.ComponentInfo.Type === 8
            })) {
                var employees = [];
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Form/GetAllUsers",
                    type: "GET"
                }).done(function (results) {
                    employees = results;
                });

                return employees;
            } else {
                return [];
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I know this isn't working because I'm returning before the call is complete. I've seen how to use `deferred`objects and what not but I can't seem to figure out how to implement it with `Vue`.

Comment: https://github.com/foxbenjaminfox/vue-async-computed might be useful.

Comment: @DanielBeck I have decided to not use a computed property for what I am trying to do. But thank you for that link. I'll definitely check it out and maybe use it in a future project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some more research I have gone another route. I agree with [Sphinx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5665870/sphinx) that I don't think what I am trying to achieve will work with a computed property.

Instead, this is what I am going with:

```
new Vue({
    el: "#formCompleteContainer",
    data: {
        form: {},
        components: [],
        employees: []
    },
    methods: {
        getEmployees: function () {
            var self = this;
            if (_.some(this.components, function (component) {
               return component.ComponentInfo.Type === 8;
            })) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Form/Form/GetAllUsers",
                    type: "GET"
                }).done(function (results) {
                    self.employees = results;
                });
            }
        }
    },
    created: function () {
        this.form = pageModel.Form;
        this.components = pageModel.Components;
    },
    mounted: function () {
        this.getEmployees();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what [vue-async-computed](https://github.com/foxbenjaminfox/vue-async-computed) is meant for. It resolves the promise you returned and handles any race conditions.

```
new Vue({
    el: "#formCompleteContainer",
    data: {
        form: {},
        components: []
    },
    asyncComputed: {
        employeeList: function () {
            if (_.some(this.components, function (component) {
                return component.ComponentInfo.Type === 8
            })) {
                return $.ajax({
                    url: "/Form/GetAllUsers",
                    type: "GET"
                });
            } else {
                return Promise.resolve([]);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: A 3rd party implementation is far from needed to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

For your use case, I don't think computed property can implement the goal.

**My solution:**

1. create one data property as one 'defered' object,
2. then uses one watch to async call your backend to get new data, finally assign to the defered object

**like below demo:**

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false
app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    product: "Boots",
    deferedProduct: ''
  },
  watch: {
    product: function (newVal, oldVal) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.deferedProduct = 'Cats in ' + newVal + '!'
      }, 1500)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    nextProduct: function () {
      this.product += 'a'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="nextProduct()">Click Me!</button>
    <h2>{{product}}</h2>
    <h2>{{deferedProduct}}</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out already, `mounted` and other 3rd party solutions can work.

However, better readability and component loading will come from putting the desired `Promise` within a `data` property. And then using the Vue lifecycle hook `created`, we can wait for that `Promise` to resolve with a `.then`.

For example:

**requestService.js**:

```
...
   async foo(){
      let myRequest = someRequest.createInstance()
      await myRequest.onReady()
      return myRequest.getSomePromise()
   } 
...
```

And then `import` the service into your component, as well as declaring a `data` prop:

**myComponent.vue**

```
...
   data: (){
      myPromiseLoc: null,
   }
...
   created: (){
      requestService.foo().then( result =>
      {
         this.myPromiseLoc = result
      }
   }
...
```

Comment: This will only do the request once when the component is loaded.

The task was to load the data only if a component with type 8 is displayed.

Comment: @Michael2 The SPECIFIC use case is always different. This questions, and the actual problem, has to do with async/await, promises, and lifecycle hooks. This answer encapsulates the users actual question just fine.